# Restrict user from choosing past time and date in date/time field in

Tags: validation-rule, admin

I have a date/time field. As soon as user enters data, I want user to choose the time from future. How can i do that?

[image]

In this pic I am able to select today, but time is 12:50. User should enter the time after 12:50 am, user shold not enter the past time.

[image]

I have tried this formula, it is only letting user not to choose past dates. How can I restrict them from choosing past time?

Comment: Based on your claims, my first thought is that this is an issue of inadvertently mixing time zones. If that's the issue, then assuming you're in India (UTC+5:30), a test you could run would be to add 5:30 to `NOW()` (which should return the time in GMT (i.e. UTC) due to how adding a datetime works would be `NOW() + 0.229167`)

Comment: Changed the time zone and tried still same issue (i am in banglore and choose GMT+5:30 India/Kolkata)

Comment: @sharanabasavajnv I am like to know for this scenario. Let's say, IST time is now 15:50 (3:50 PM). So if the user give the `dateandtime__c` value as today 20:10 (8:10 PM) means it's need to allow the user to save the record right? if Yes, what will happen if the same user edit the same record on tomorrow 09:10 AM (09:10 AM) **during that time the given dateandtime__c value is past right?**.. So is the system going to prevent Edit functionality once after user enter the `dateandtime` value for that record?